Доступ из интернета для CentOS 9.0.0
Я новичок-самоучка в вопросах развёртывания веб-серверов на Linux. Недавно поставили задачу: развернуть копию коробочного портала для тестирования доработок. Сделал по инструкции, развернул ВМ, кинул туда BitrixENV, восстановил из бэкапа БД. Но возникла проблема: сама копия портала недоступна из интернета! Есть ли у кого-нибудь чёткая инструкция, как настроить доступ из интернета к веб-серверу?

Никто не знает,  где вы что развернули и не имеет значения, есть ли тамi Bitrix с БД - да хоть игровой сервер.  Ваш вопрос слишком общий (без подробностей). Если вы что-то сделали на домашнем компьютере, то читайте про проброс портов на роутере. Если вы что развернули внутри организации (говоря простыми словами), то обращайтесь к администратору сети. В итоге: ваш вопрос очень общий и на него нет однозначного ответа.
